# Bootstrap Table delete dynamic element after sorting the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have an issue with wenzhixin `Bootstrap Table`, in one of the table cell there is a button, and once this button is pressed it is deleted and a new button with popover is created dynamically.

The problem is once the table is sorted - the new button is deleted and the old button comes alive.

All the description that i have described is available in the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eitanmg/gmtm3d9k/1/

How can I keep the new button after the table is sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue of the plugin. The issue is reported [here](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/2841) and it is still open. The sort basically re-renders the table back to its original state, discarding all dynamically made modifications to it.

I suggest using [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com) for sorting purposes.

Comment: tablesorter indeed working, but destroy boostrap css :/

Comment: @Eitanmg how is it affecting bootstrap ?